# Bluetooth LE only devices not being discovered Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, google-chrome, kde, ubuntu-studio

I am trying to connect a Bluetooth LE device to Chrome. I think I have the Chrome settings correct but the device is not being discovered either by Chrome or by the KDE Bluetooth manager. I have two different BLE devices, neither of which are being found. They can both be found and connected on my Android phone and via that I can read their info so no issues with the devices themselves. All other Bluetooth devices I have tried have been discovered and connected on Ubuntu Studio which is why I suspect it is an issue with the BLE discovery.

Bluetooth is integrated on Intel AX201 Wifi.

Chrome flags #enable-experimental-web-platform-features and #enable-web-bluetooth are
enabled.

Bluez version 5.64-0ubuntu1.1

Any help would be gratefully received.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been as simple as disabling then reenabling Bluetooth, which I had done previously but it worked this time. Now the device is saved it will connect. Needs to be connected via KDE manager before Chrome will recognise it.